# My WinEdt can only debug one file

Tags: debugging, winedt

I came across a weird question... The thing is, suddenly without
and reasons, I could only pdfTeXify one file in my WinEdt. As you know, we
usually open lots of files which we have edited historically in the WinEdt,
and we can just latex any one as we like. However, I could only latex one
now (the first opened one), and if I want to latex others, I have to close
all the other latex file except the one I want to debug. I really have no
idea why, and this bugs me a lot since it's really inconvenient.

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Did you activate the "set main file"-Option? (Menu Project, or the small documents in the toolbar with the + and the -).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Sorry I'm new here. I see, but could u kindly tell me how to answer someone or add a comment? And how to vote?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: It's solved! Yes, I just inactivate the "set main file" option...

Answer (score 2):

You probably activated the "set main file"-Option. `Menu->Project`, or the small documents in the toolbar with the `+`  and the `-`.